# Apache IoTDB deployed in k8s?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to deal with the `unknown` cluster status problem aside from parsing datanode of
I feel like the mechanism of Apache IoTDB that parse datanode names cannot be deployed in k8s. Has anyone successfully done it? The current status of my cluster is `unknown`, but it seems that data can be written into IoTDB when testing. Since IoTDB is deployed in k8s, the datanode cannot be pinged on the confignode in image. It should be that the datanode name cannot be resolved, since the confignode is full of this error: `Could not resolve host: datanode-0`. Is there any other reason to solve the `unknown` cluster problem (since cannot use ping to solve it)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `debian` instead of `alpine` in k8s settings for the base mirroring format of data in Apache IoTDB. See if setting this and restart the system can solve your problem.